# Sharing a JSON file between iOS and Android projects

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I have inherited a Xamarin project (not Xamarin.Forms) and right now it has three major components.

An iOS project, an Android project and finally a *Shared Project* (not a PCL and not a .Net Standard project).

Despite the *Shared Project*, the application reads a json file included within the assets folders of each project. The file is a duplicate. I feel like this file should be in the *Shared Project*

To clarify, this is the structure:

### Shared Project

No Assets

### iOS

Resources/test.json

### Android

Assets/test.json

I believe the `test.json` file should exist as one file in the Shared Project. My first step was to make this move and I changed the file to `Build Action=Content` which worked for the iOS project. It seems however the Android project does not get this file. I cannot find it anywhere in the compiled and archived .apk file.

Is there anything I can do about this, or do I need to accept this design flaw and build a .Net Standard library or PCL? If so, how exactly do you make a .Net Standard or PCL for a non-Xamarin.Forms project.

Comment: Not a design flaw, just the way each platform work with "content". A way to share a "file" without including it each platform-specific application (or library) is to embed it as a .Net assembly resource in a  NetStd/PCL library and include that library in each app. Personally I highly against permanently consuming memory with embedded  resources in assemblies and create symlinks within each application project to a central location in the solution and make use the platform specific bundle options...

Comment: No no no, I don't mean design flaw like that! I meant in the way the app I inherited was developed.

Comment: hahahahah, ok.. ;-) .... Shared Projects do have their benefits, including one less assembly to slow the app startup time ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is your use case? If you just need to read the test.json at runtime and parse it using .NET code, you can use embedded resources, details here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/files/

If you need the file to go into iOS reosurces / Android assets folder, you can keep the test.json file only once in the solution (either in shared project or as a solution item) and add it as link to both iOS and Android project - here is screen shot how to do it in Visual Studio.

[image: Add as link]

You can do it also in Visual Studio for Mac - right click on the containing folder in solution explorer, choose Add Files and you will get the following prompt - choose Add a link to the file

[image: VS For mac]

Comment: Learn something new everyday. I had no idea you could add as a link in Visual Studio... I will play around with that. And I am not 100% sure what the use case is. As I mention I inherited this application so I am trying to understand exactly how it is built and trying to fix problems as I see them without going too far into it. I have looked at the link you provided and it seems that code is very specific to Xamarin.Forms, or I have failed to included a missing component. I will explore that as well!

Comment: After review, the linking was the perfect solution to my specific problem. It is working perfectly! Thank you.

Comment: @Rakshasas Wich method did you use to load your .json file from Share project ? I have the same case as you but cannot read file on Android. On iOS it's working great. Thank you :)

Comment: @Lapinou I did not have the Json in the shared project. The problem with that is you can't pick the resource type properly for both projects. What I did was create another folder for "Shared Content" and placed in there. I added items from that folder as items in a Solution Folder for easy access. Then, in the iOS Resources, I added as a link using the method spatialguy told me about. In Android I did the same thing under the Assets folder.